# oidc-client or oidc-token-manager in react+flux application

Tags: reactjs, flux, openid-connect

I am writing a react+flux application and I have set up a IdentityServer as an OpenID Connect provider. There are two libraries provided by the IdentityServer guys that make handling the client side a lot easier.

These libraries are [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client) and [oidc-token-manager](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-token-manager)

I'd like to use one of the two but I'm having some trouble thinking of how I should use them with the flux architecture.

Do you have any experience using these libraries or IdentityServer in general with a react+flux application?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but did you find a solution? I am running ASP.NET core and IdentityServer on the server with React front end and I am looking for tutorials or guidance also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an updated library called [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). It combines the functionality of both oidc-client & oidc-token-manager. I recommend using this as a basis for including it in your flux app.

If you're looking for flux I'm afraid there is no direct adaptation for it. But there is a library called [redux-oidc](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc) which wraps the oidc-client-js library for use in a redux app (I'm the author). If you want to use flux you'd have to wrap it similarily to my library.